# $X$ and $Y$ are iid. and $XY$ is Normal distributed. What distribution does $X$ and $Y$ have?

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, products

Is there a distribution, $D$, such that if $X,Y\sim D$ are iid., then the product $XY$ is Normal distributed?

I natural idea would be to sample $X',Y'\sim N(0,1)$ and then take $X=\mathrm{sign}(X')\sqrt{|X'|}$ and similarly for $Y$, but that doesn't quite seem to give the right. For one thing the variance is too small.

I'm wondering if there is some other way I may sample $X$ and $Y$ instead?
In general, I'm interested in ways to split a given distribution into a product of two iid. samples this way.

Comment: Related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199667/square-root-of-normal-distribution

Comment: @Snaw Thank you! I don't think I can close my question as a duplicate, since the other answer is on MO. Should I just delete it?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the right thing to do in such cases. I see no harm in keeping it open and maybe someone will have something interesting to add. Maybe you could add an answer that summarizes what the answer on MO says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the following code to sample "square root normals" based on Pinelis' paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.09838.pdf

```
def pinelis(samples, n, k=2):
    x = np.log(2*n) / (2*k)
    gs = np.random.standard_gamma(1/k, size=(samples, n))
    x -= gs @ (1/(1 + 2*np.arange(n)))
    r = 1-2*np.random.randint(2, size=samples)
    return r * np.exp(x)
```

In the code I truncate the infinite sum in Pinelis' paper to $n$ terms.
The parameter $k$ can be set larger than 2 to get a distribution such that $X_1X_2\cdots X_k\sim N(0,1)$.

The following plot shows that convergence of the product to the real normal distribution is pretty good already after $n=5$:
[image: normal-distributions]

For those curious about what this "square root distribution" looks like in PDF form, I plotted the same three $n$ values here:
[image: sqrt-distributions]